Issue understanding subnetting and connection issues
I am in the process of planning a network overhaul and have run into a small problem with my logic.
I have setup a new VLAN in our VMWare, switch and firewall, and deployed som virtual machines for testing network rules, vm discovery etc, and have already run into a small issue. I have tried searching for some guide but have not found a solid explanation to why my logic is wrong, and how to solve the issue.
I have setup a VLAN where I'm planning to use three subnets. I do not want the VMs on one subnet to be able to connect to a VM on another subnet without a firewall rule.
I was planning on having one VLAN, and use three subnets for firewall rules.
10.50.0.0/16
- 10.50.0.0/24
- 10.50.10.0/24
- 10.50.20.0/24

These are the VMs I have deployed using terraform:
test-admin  ipv4_address: 10.50.0.10   ipv4_netmask: 24  ipv4_gateway: 10.50.0.1
test-db     ipv4_address: 10.50.10.10  ipv4_netmask: 24  ipv4_gateway: 10.50.10.1
test-app-0  ipv4_address: 10.50.20.10  ipv4_netmask: 24  ipv4_gateway: 10.50.20.1
test-app-1  ipv4_address: 10.50.20.11  ipv4_netmask: 24  ipv4_gateway: 10.50.20.1

I have created a firewall rule that allows me to SSH into VLAN-Test (10.50.0.0/16) from my VPN, but I can only access "test-admin".
I was planning to use /24 addresses in the firewall to manage access between the different subnets for specific services.
ex:
FROM 10.50.0.0/24   TO 10.50.10.0/24  ALLOW SSH
FROM 10.50.0.0/24   TO 10.50.20.0/24  ALLOW SSH
FROM 10.50.20.0/24  TO 10.50.10.0/24  ALLOW MYSQL

I am hoping for a good explanation to why my thinking isn't working, or if there is something I can do in terraform to make this work, I was thinking that every IP on the 10.50.0.0/16 network would be accessible even if the IP of the VM is 10.50.10.10/24 or 10.50.10.10/32.
I tried changing the gateway for "test-db" to the same as "test-admin" but that did not help. When I changed netmask on "test-db" to /16 I was able to SSH into the VM, but I was also able to SSH from "test-db" to "test-admin" which there is no firewall rule that allows, and is something that we explicitly do not want.
I have tried to find documentation about terraform syntax and if you can specify subnets or something like that in the network block of e resource but have not found anything.
Thank you in advance


I was planning on having one VLAN, and use three subnets for firewall rules.

That may be a problem. While you may use multiple IP subnets within a single VLAN, only strict L2 separation = multiple VLANs really separate your host zones. Also, DHCP won't work without proper separation.
Generally, you should use a 1:1 mapping between VLANs and IP subnets. There are very few scenarios where anything else makes sense.
For basic connectivity, check that each host can ping its default gateway (or each gateway that is configured). Then, at least temporarily permit ICMP echo/reply and ping across the gateway(s).

Thank you, my original idea was to deploy multiple VLANs (one for each service) and setup rules for how the VLANs are allowed to communicate with each other, but was instructed to try this route instead.

If the subnets are about controlling traffic and security then you do need VLANs. Without distinct VLANs, any host can simply use an IP address from another subnet and circumvent your filter.


I was thinking that every IP on the 10.50.0.0/16 network would be accessible even if the IP of the VM is 10.50.10.10/24 or 10.50.10.10/32.

The "/24" or "/32" tells the VM what is directly accessible and what is not. Anything that's not within range as defined by the netmask, will be going through the default gateway and back.
So yes, the VM technically can access the entire /16, but won't, because it doesn't know that – its configuration only specifies the /24 as accessible directly. (Of course, it can still access the rest of the /16 via the router, which may apply firewall rules.)
The first problem though is that the router knows that the entire /16 is on the same interface, and even as it reflects the packets back from VM1 to VM5, it'll also send out an ICMP 'Redirect' informing them both that a more direct path is available. As soon as the VMs accept the redirect they'll start talking directly to each other, bypassing all router filtering.
(And of course if you assume a malicious attacker who has root...they can easily find out that the entire /16 is freely accessible.)
Second problem: given that you only consider IPv4 filtering, all your VMs can still access each other through IPv6 – they all have automatic link-local addresses in the same fe80::/64 range. (And if you ever plan to deploy full IPv6, it'll be a headache due to the way SLAAC works...)
The last problem is that it's just very easy to end up with asymmetric configs, or with half-broken configs that don't work as expected, or which work when they oughtn't, etc. It's an additional administration cost.
